# What's The Gas Discharge After Landing Finished For SpaceShip2?

Tags: propulsion, fuel, virgin-galactic

What's the gas discharge after landing finished For SpaceShip2?

Why did they did it right after landing finished while crew were on board.

[image]

Comment: To make it safe, do they have to vent remaining oxidizer? If so, do they do it after landing for some reason?

Comment: @uhoh I thought I saw venting (out of the nozzle) right after engine shutdown on the live stream

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 I thought that that was just smoldering rubber, and for some chemistry reason the particles changed from black soot white white ash but I haven't a clue.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 That it is transparent yet so visible suggests a substantial difference in density, which is why I think it must be something cold like an expanded gas. However, back in 2018 this says [At around 50,000ft,   the tail-booms were lowered again and, while jettisoning the remaining oxidizer, Unity turned towards Mojave for the glide home and a smooth runway landing.](https://www.virgingalactic.com/articles/VSS-Unity-First-Powered-Flight/)